# Google cloud batch does not run docker login for private images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-batch

I am trying to run a google cloud batch job using a private docker image from dockerhub. The job always fails to pull the image with exit code 125 and in the logs I can see:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for privateorg/image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

This is the task spec I'm using as per the documentation:

```json
    {
      "taskSpec": {
        "runnables": [
          {
            "container": {
              "imageUri": "privateorg/image:tag",
              "entrypoint": "/bin/sh",
              "commands": [
                "-c",
                "sleep 1h"
              ],
              "username": "${dockerhub_user}",
              "password": "${dockerhub_pass}"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "taskCount": 1,
      "parallelism": 1
    }
```

I am not sure it is relevant, but the job spec does not include a custom instance template. It only uses instance policy:

```json
  "allocationPolicy": {
    "instances": [
      {
        "installGpuDrivers": true,
        "policy": {
          "machineType": "a2-highgpu-1g",
          "provisioning_model": "STANDARD",
          "accelerators": [
            {
              "type": "nvidia-tesla-a100",
              "count": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "location": {
      "allowedLocations": [
        "zones/me-west1-b",
        "zones/me-west1-c"
      ]
    },
    "serviceAccount": {
      "email": "${batch_service_account_email}"
    }
  },
```

I am aware I also need to supply options to the docker image in order to be able to use the GPU, but I've not gone to that point considering I cannot even run the docker image.

- I have verified the credentials are correct by creating a job with runnable script with command sleep 1h and manually running docker login/pull/run. Prior to running docker login there were no credentials in the instance.
- I have tried to supply the full image url, as well as with explicit latest tag.
- I have tried to pull public image, which obviously works - but I can still not see any docker login in the logs.

Comment: Just a couple things to clarify, are the strings ${dockerhub_user} and ${dockerhub_pass} literally in your job spec or are those just for StackOverflow, and in the actual job spec you have the literal credentials?

When you run the sleep 1h script job, do you mean that you then SSH to the job's VM and manually run docker login/pull/run? What if you change the job's script so the script does docker login/pull/run instead of sleep? Does that job succeed?

Comment: Hi Aaron, the strings are just for stackoverflow - in the actual definition they are literals.

The sleep 1h is just for testing with public image. I ssh to the machine, do docker login manually and run docker pull/run and everything works. But obviously I don't need a batch job to run sleep so when I change to the actual script and the image is private, the instance fails to pull the image.

I cannot change the script to do docker pull because the script runs inside the docker image that I need to pull.